# UDID Replacement?

Tags: iphone, ios

I know `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` is being rejected, I used :

```
- (NSString *) uniqueDeviceIdentifier{
    NSString *macaddress = [[UIDevice currentDevice] macaddress];
    NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

    NSString *stringToHash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",macaddress,bundleIdentifier];
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [stringToHash stringFromMD5];

    return uniqueIdentifier;
}
```

If my method is not approved by Apple, what method can I get a unique identifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This project does something similar to what you're doing: https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5.  I believe it is being accepted by Apple for now.  To actually answer your question, there is no other (public) way of getting a id that is not only unique but the same for every app.  @Vishal's method of using:

```
+ (NSString *)GetUUID {
  CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
  CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
  CFRelease(theUUID);
  return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

and @JeffWolski's method of using:

```
[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

work if you don't need the device id to be consistant between apps and just need a way to identify that specific device within your own. If you need a device ID that works between apps, you will need to use the devices MAC address either using your code or a open source project.

**UPDATE**

I just found another solution.  You can use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]`.  Again, this device id will be unique to your app. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor

Comment: Your method will work; however, like the other methods, it will be unique to your app because you are appending the bundle id to the mac address.  The mac address is unique the device where as the bundle id is unique the the app and device.  If you want it to be unique to the device (making it the same for every app), you could remove the part that appends the bundle id

Answer (score 3):

This is new in iOS 6.  It gives you a UUID that conforms to RFC 4122.

`[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];`

Answer (score 3):

Use this CFUUIDCreate() to create a UUID:

```
+ (NSString *)GetUUID {
  CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
  CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
  CFRelease(theUUID);
  return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

And the UDID is only deprecated in iOS 5.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do it use [openUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) to replace it.